# React Native legacy_createStore undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, mobile-development

store.js :

```
export default {
    nameList: [],
}
```

reducers.js :

```
    export default function (state, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case "ADD_LIST":
                const {name} = action.payload
                const newList = [...state.nameList, name]
                return { ...state, newList }
                break
    
            default:
                return state
        }
    }
```

Provider.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { legacy_createStore as createStore } from "redux";

import reducers from "./reducers";
import initialState from './store'

const UserProvider = ({children}) => {

    const store = createStore(reducers,initialState)

    return <Provider store = {store}> {children}</Provider>
}

export default UserProvider
```

Those are my redux codes and I don't think there's something wrong with them but I'm getting "undefined is not a function" error with createStore.

dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.11",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.24.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.0"
  },
```

Those are my dependencies as well. How can I fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you run ```npm install``` and/or ```watchman watch-del-all```?

Comment: Yes, I installed my dependencies with npm install.

Comment: Delete the package-lock.json and the node_modules folder and reinstall the modules.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but It didn't work, what should I do?

Comment: Check the content of your node_modules ```vi node_modules/redux/src/index.js``` , is there an export of legacy_createStore